# Angular application using a index.php instead of index.html

Tags: angular

Is it possible (and how) to run an Angular 2+ app with index.php instead of index.html, so I can render the content of the index.php on the server side. It is not Angular SSR (Angular server side rendering) which is about serving all routes from server side. It is just about rendering the content of index.html on the server side when the user calls the app for the first time.

Comment: Yes you can, just make sure there is an <app-root> in there and you have replaced index.html inside angular.json with index.php.. However.. ng serve won’t just work anymore after that as the angular development server does not understand php.. so you’ll have to come up with a solution for that if you still want to make use of ng serve and if you need php rendered stuff in your index during development.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in PHP so this solution should be revised by an expert, but actually it works for me no need to care about php code for development, it display image in social media Whatsapp,
Facebook, Twitter

I am on apache server so modify accordingly:

`.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirection to HTTPS:
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  # Redirection of requests to index.php
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  # Redirect all non-file routes to index.php
  RewriteRule ^(?!.*\.).*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

`index.php`

```
<?php
  include 'meta_function.php';
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  $doc->loadHTMLFile("index.html");
  libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
  $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');
  $base = $doc->createElement('base');
  $base->setAttribute("href", (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

  $actual_link = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  $parsed_url = parse_url($actual_link, PHP_URL_PATH);
  $trimmed_url = trim($parsed_url);
  $splited_url = explode("/", $trimmed_url);

  array_shift($splited_url);
  $arr = Array();
  if ( $splited_url[0] == "product") {
      $url = "https://yourserver.herokuapp.com/api/items/" . $splited_url[1];
      $curl = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $store = curl_exec($curl);
      $arr = json_decode($store, true);
      curl_close($curl);
  }
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      if ($node->tagName=='base') {
        $node->setAttribute("href", (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
      } else if ($node->tagName =='head' && count($arr) != 0) {
          $metas = meta_function($doc, $arr, $actual_link); 
          foreach ($metas as $meta) {
            $node->appendChild($meta);
          }
      }
  }
  echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

`meta_function.php`

```
<?php
    function meta_function($doc, $arr, $actual_link) {
        $og_image = $doc->createElement('meta');
        $og_image->setAttribute("property", "og:image");
        $og_image->setAttribute("content", $arr["thumb"]);
        
        $og_image_secure_url = $doc->createElement('meta');
        $og_image_secure_url->setAttribute("property", "og:image:secure_url");
        $og_image_secure_url->setAttribute("content", $arr["thumb"]);
        
        $url = $doc->createElement('meta');
        $url->setAttribute("property", "og:url");
        $url->setAttribute("content", $actual_link);
        
        $og_title = $doc->createElement('meta');
        $og_title->setAttribute("property", "og:title");
        $og_title->setAttribute("content", $arr["titleAr"]);
        
        $og_description = $doc->createElement('meta');
        $og_description->setAttribute("property", "og:description");
        $og_description->setAttribute("content", $arr["description"]);
        
        // ETC... OTHERA METAS.
        return Array(
            $url,
            $og_image,
            $og_image_secure_url,
            $og_title,
            $og_description,
        );
    }
?>
```

This requires you do not use `{ useHash: true }` is your **app.module.ts**